# How to fix Prisma 'change would violate the required relation'

Tags: typescript, prisma

I am having some trouble with prisma. Apparently there's something wrong with my current schema. After adding one instance of a `PublicKey`, I am unable to add another. I get this error:

```bash
PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.publicKey.create()` invocation:


The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'PublicKeyToUser' between the `PublicKey` and `User` models.

{
  code: 'P2014',
  clientVersion: '5.0.0',
  meta: {
    relation_name: 'PublicKeyToUser',
    model_a_name: 'PublicKey',
    model_b_name: 'User'
  }
}
```

This is my current schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum Role {
  ADMIN
  USER
}

model PublicKey {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  key String @unique
  ownerId String @unique
  owner User @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  deletedAt DateTime?
  keyActivities KeyActivity[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model User{
  id String @id
  role Role
  publicKey PublicKey?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

This is the calling function (`createPublicKeyAndDeleteOld`):

```
export async function createPublicKey(data: CreateKeyData) {
  const { ownerId, key } = data;

  const response = await db.publicKey.create({
    data: {
      key,
      owner: {
        connect: { id: ownerId },
      },
    },
  });

  return response;
}

export async function createPublicKeyAndDeleteOld(data: CreateKeyData) {
  const activePublicKey = await getActivePublicKey(data.ownerId);

  if (activePublicKey) {
    await db.$transaction([
      db.publicKey.create({
        data: {
          key: data.key,
          owner: {
            connect: { id: data.ownerId },
          },
        },
      }),
      db.publicKey.update({
        where: {
          id: activePublicKey.id,
        },
        data: {
          deletedAt: new Date(),
        },
      }),
    ]);
  } else {
    const response = await createPublicKey(data);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Any idea, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the foreign key is a unique value as you specified in the ownerid,

so this leads to having only one ownerid with the same value in the whole table, which is not the case you are looking to

as you don't delete the key

you can remove the @unique and it will work

Comment: This fixed it. I had to also change `publicKey` field to `publicKeys PublicKey[]`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following sentence next to the foreign key:

```
 - onDelete: Cascade
```

Example:

```
Model Post {
user User @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```